# Convert UTF-8 characters to nearest equivalent ASCII characters using c++ (without winapi)

Tags: c++, utf-8, ascii

Does anybody have a code snippet what could convert at least the most common characters for the european languages?
For example:

> testáén

as a UTF-8 encoded string (i.e. bytes in hex: 74 65 73 74 c3 a1 c3 a9 6e 0)

to

> testaen

(I'd like to use c/c++ and std, or small crossplatform libs)

Comment: I get that `Ã` maps to `a`, but why does `©` map to `e`? And what happened to the second `Ã`? Have you tried writing code that does this?

Comment: Hey! i used this tool: http://www.cafewebmaster.com/online_tools/utf_decode

Comment: Ã¡ converts to á and i need a

Comment: Ã© converts to é and i'd like e

Comment: Did you mean to write "testáén" should map to "testaen" instead of "testÃ¡Ã©n"? I think you may have pasted something which has lost its correct encoding.

Comment: Try `iconv()` with the `TRANSLIT` option.

Comment: Hey! I have a binary data containing 9 bytes (+ null termination), containing the bytes: "testÃ¡Ã©n" (ansi encoded). But this is encoded, and i need a character array containing 7 characters (+ null termination)

Comment: Wait, so do you want to convert UTF-8 or characters in the local encoding? ("ANSI encoded" implies the latter.)

Comment: Perhaps when posting _bytes_ you should post their numerical values to avoid any confusion (bytes don't need an encoding to be converted to bytes). SO uses utf-8 so you should be able to use all the characters you need when displaying _characters_.

Comment: You check the [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) project page. It is cross platform and comply with ISO standard.

Comment: sry for confusing. i'd like to convert those 9 bytes, and i posted those ansi encoded :) (Yes, u are right, i should post it as hex: 74 65 73 74 c3a1 c3 a9 6e 0) (i'm getting it from the web, and i think it is utf8 encoded string, because this tool decodes them well: cafewebmaster.com/online_tools/utf_decode )

Comment: Why not just write it yourself? Get Unicode documentation and implement it.

Comment: @Alex: Because there's no point in reinventing the wheel if there's already a perfectly good one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's code that handles converting characters from the ISO-8859-1 range to ascii. A replacement character is used for everything else outside ascii.

```
#include <codecvt>
#include <array>
#include <string>

#include <iostream>

constexpr char const *rc = "?"; // replacement_char

// table mapping ISO-8859-1 characters to similar ASCII characters
std::array<char const *,96> conversions = {{
   " ",  "!","c","L", rc,"Y", "|","S", rc,"C","a","<<",   rc,  "-",  "R", "-",
    rc,"+/-","2","3","'","u", "P",".",",","1","o",">>","1/4","1/2","3/4", "?", 
   "A",  "A","A","A","A","A","AE","C","E","E","E", "E",  "I",  "I",  "I", "I",
   "D",  "N","O","O","O","O", "O","*","0","U","U", "U",  "U",  "Y",  "P","ss",
   "a",  "a","a","a","a","a","ae","c","e","e","e", "e",  "i",  "i",  "i", "i",
   "d",  "n","o","o","o","o", "o","/","0","u","u", "u",  "u",  "y",  "p", "y"    
}};

template <class Facet>
class usable_facet : public Facet {
public:
    using Facet::Facet;
    ~usable_facet() {}
};

std::string to_ascii(std::string const &utf8) {
    std::wstring_convert<usable_facet<std::codecvt<char32_t,char,std::mbstate_t>>,
                         char32_t> convert;
    std::u32string utf32 = convert.from_bytes(utf8);

    std::string ascii;
    for (char32_t c : utf32) {
        if (c<=U'\u007F')
            ascii.push_back(static_cast<char>(c));
        else if (U'\u00A0'<=c && c<=U'\u00FF')
            ascii.append(conversions[c - U'\u00A0']);
        else
            ascii.append(rc);
    }
    return ascii;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << to_ascii(u8"testáén\n");
}
```

Comment: Note that std::wstring_convert is deprecated in C++17.

Comment: Note also that in visual studio you need to use uint32_t instead of char32_t https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8f40dcd8-c67f-4eba-9134-a19b9178e481/vs-2015-rc-linker-stdcodecvt-error?forum=vcgeneral

Answer (score 4):

There is a gigantic collection of Unicode characters that you'd need to handle. So the criteria of 'small' is an impossible criteria. The ICU library contains what you need, but for this reason you won't find it small. You'll need, for example, to deal with both composed and non-composed modifiers.

If you really only care about a small subset of the possible Unicode characters, then you can create your own simple mapping table.

Answer (score 3):

> I'd like to use c/c++ and std, or small crossplatform libs

Unfortunately, I'm not sure that a library exists that meets all of your criteria.

The smallest thing you're likely to find is [iconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/), and its UTF-8-to-ASCII converter may not do exactly what you want.

I'm pretty sure that [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) can do what you want, and while ICU is cross-platform, nobody has ever accused it of being *small*.

Comment: You can compile small versions of ICU that only include the minimal dataset that you want. It is fiddly, though.

Comment: You could use ICU to produce a static trie of utf-8 => ascii conversion sequences. It should be quite small, extremeley fast, and certainly cross-platform.